# Error in sqlite3 query where a field is of text type

Tags: database

I'm trying to do a simple query in SQLITE3 but it doesn't work, any idea where's my error?

I'm using the nodejs sqlite3 driver

SELECT * FROM usuarios;

worked but

SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE "jared" doesn't work.

here's a screnshoot

[image: my terminal]

Comment: Use single quotes, i.e. `WHERE nombre LIKE '%jared%'`

Comment: already tried, didn't work though.

Comment: Then it means you have no matching records containing `jared`.

Comment: but I already did a query of all my records and my only row contains jared as the value of the field "nombre" it's weird...

Comment: well the error was my database extension , I used db.sqlite extension so I changed to a .db extension and it worked! thank you anyway.